# Find the best constant in this complex analysis problem

Tags: complex-analysis, summation

I stumbled upon a problem that gives me trouble and is quite interesting but I can't do it.
Here it goes.

Let $(z_1, z_2, ... z_n)\in \mathbb{C^n}$, $J \subset$ {$1,2,..n$} for $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $ S_J := |\sum_{j \in J}z_j$|
Clearly $S_J\leq \sum_{j\in J}|z_j|\leq \sum_{j=1}^{n}|z_j|:=S$

For $n=2$, prove that there exists $J$, such that $S_J\geq aS$ and $a\in \mathbb{R}$. Prove that $a=\frac{1}{2}$ is the best constant.
For $n=3$, prove that there exists $J$, such that $S_J\geq bS$ and $b\in \mathbb{R}$. Prove that $b=\frac{1}{3}$ is the best constant.
What's the best constant if $n\geq 4$ ?

Comment: Where did you "stumble across" this problem?  What have you tried?  What are your thoughts?

Comment: A list of problems to prepare for my final exam in Measure Theory and Integration. 
I tried triangular inequality, I tried to use somehow Cauchy-Schwarz and using a sum of cartezian products, I have tried to find m such that S_j/S >= 1. We didn't work so much with complex analysis, but rather Lebesgue/Riemann integration, Lp spaces and Fourier Series and Fourier Transform. I have no idea how to solve this tho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to write $\left|\sum_{j \in J} z_j\right|$ as $S_J$, not $S_j$: $j$ is just a "dummy index".

For $n=2$, $S_{\{1\}} + S_{\{2\}} = |s_1| + |s_2| = S$ so $\max(S_{\{1\}}, S_{\{2\}}) \ge S/2$.  Similarly for $n=3$, $\max(S_{\{1\}}, S_{\{2\}}, S_{\{3\}}) \ge S/3$,
and in general $\max(S_{\{1\}}, \ldots, S_{\{n\}}) \ge S/n$.

To see that $a = 1/2$ is the best constant for $n=2$, you can take $z_1 = 1$ and $z_2 = -1$.  To see that $a=1/3$ is the best for $n=3$, you can take $z_1, z_2, z_3$ the three cube roots of $1$.

I don't know the best constants when $n > 3$.

EDIT: see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1917993/maximum-value-c-s-t-exists-a-subset-s-of-z-1-z-2-ldots-z-n-s-t?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks! It helps me a lot. I still don't see how is this problem related to what we learnt in Measure and Integration, but it's not up to me to judge my professor.